# Loop all Magento Cookies & Delete

Tags: php, magento, cookies

I have a Magento site with a location to IP plugin. It uses cookies heavily. Because of this, I need to clear all cookies magento sets. I have what I believe is the correct code but it's not working:

```
$cookies = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get();
foreach($cookies as $cookie)
{
     Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete($cookie->name, $cookie->path);   
}
```

Some cookies are set on the path '/' and some on /another'. I would like to clear all to avoid any confusion.

Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because $cookie->name and $cookie->path are not objects.  To get your loop to work try this.

```
$names = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get(); //This returns an array of all cookies
foreach($names as $name) { //loop through the array
    $cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get($name); //get the cookie object for each cookie
    $path = $cookie->getPath(); //get the path for the cookie

    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete($name, $path); //delete that cookie
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the sessions too, e.g.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsetAll();
```

Take a look at `Mage_Persistent_IndexController::unsetCookieAction()` (store.com/persistent/index/unsetCookie/)

Comment: Thanks @Steve Robbins, so the code I have can stay and this should go before it? Sorry, I'm new to Magento!

Comment: Looking at how they did it in that controller, your code would go after.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Robbins - however I get the same error of: Trying to get property of non-object on this line: Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete($cookie->name, $cookie->path);